# RPi Camera V2 not detected with Raspberry Pi4 running Ubuntu 20.05 LTS

Tags: boot, camera, ubuntu, picamera, firmware

I am running into a problem in which I am unable to have my Pi detect my new RPi Camera V2. I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (focal) since I am working on a robotics project that requires ROS2(foxy).

- I initially set up the Camera and installed the necessary drivers/software
- I then ran `vcgencmd get_camera` and the output resulted in `supported=0 detected=0'
- I searched the problem and inputted `start_x=1 and gpu_mem=128` in the /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt file and rebooted.
- I `sudo apt upgrade' and` sudo apt update' and rebooted
- I then installed the raspi-config tool and tried to enable my Camera in the interface options but got an error saying `Your firmware appears to be out of date (no start_x.elf). Please update`

I looked in my /boot/firmware directory and I do see a start_x.elf file. I am curious as to what could be the problem or if there's anything else I can try to detect my camera. I have ran out of options to try with the knowledge I have. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated and thanks for reading all that :)